# Decompile class, amend and re-add to ear

Tags: java, class, ear, decompiler

I have an Ear file. I took a Java class file out, decompiled it and edited it.

I now want to recompile the new Java source file and re-add the resulting class file to my new Ear.

When I tried to recompile the new Java source file, the compiler complained about unrecognised classes, imports etc. I expected this.

My question is, can I recompile this new class and add it to my new Ear?

Comment: I have done something similar, but instead of a single class I decompile the whole package and modify the class I needed, and then re-package. Also make sure you have all dependencies in your classpath

Comment: Why are there so many down votes...?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the classes needed are also in the EAR. If not, you need to create stubs for all the classes, it needs.

Comment: Should I put the entire Ear file on the classpath when compiling then?

Comment: @heyya99 the compiler won't look at jar file inside an EAR.  You need to include the JAR files on the class path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to add all the dependencies to the classpath

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned the idea of decompile, recompile and readd. I rebuilt the entire Ear from scratch.